# jQuery Mobile Themeroller beta

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

Is there currently a beta version of the Themeroller for use with version 1.4  alpha 2 jQuery Mobile?

It's difficult to gauge how well the new jQuery with a focus on vectorized graphics is working without the colors in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no beta version of the jQuery Mobile Themeroller for 1.4.

**Jquery Mobile's Blog States:**

> *We are also still working on updating the ThemeRoller for 1.4, which takes more time than usual because of all the changes we made in the
>   theme CSS.*

The latest CSS Version rc1 style sheet can be linked to here.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.css">
```

This stylesheet consist of only:

```
data-theme="a" (Light - White Theme)
```

**AND**

```
data-theme="b" (Dark - Black Theme)
```

Judging by the timing of releases I suspect the Themeroller 1.4 will be released around January.